# What's the reason for iteration runtime being so much higher than runtime of consecutive steps?

Tags: rust

[[PLAYGROUND]](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=504ecc7e0c18e6175337c0315a5a61ea)

I believe the below result is self-explanatory. The final meta-measurement proves what I suspected (that measuring itself takes this much time) to be false. The first iteration's runtime is on average more than 4 times higher than consecutive steps + 3 measurements' time.

What's the reason for that?

```
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let v:Vec<(i128,i128)>=vec![
        (23,55007766),
        (45,55884433),
        (42,22663355)
    ];
    for i in v{
        let now_ = Instant::now();
            let now = Instant::now();
            let part1 = i.0*i.1;
            let then = Instant::now();
            println!("runtime_part1: {} ns",(then-now).as_nanos());
            
            let now = Instant::now();
            let part2 = part1*i.1;
            let then = Instant::now();
            println!("runtime_part2: {} ns",(then-now).as_nanos());
            
            let now = Instant::now();
            let part3 = i.0+part2;
            let then = Instant::now();
            println!("runtime_part3: {} ns",(then-now).as_nanos());
        let then_ = Instant::now();
        println!("runtime_iter: {} ns",(then_-now_).as_nanos());
    };
    
    let now = Instant::now();
        let now_ = Instant::now();
        (|| 123123*123123);
        let then_ = Instant::now();
        println!("print: {} ns",(then_-now_).as_nanos());
    let then = Instant::now();
    println!("runtime_measurement: {} ns",(then-now).as_nanos());
}
```

```
runtime_part1: 30 ns
runtime_part2: 50 ns
runtime_part3: 40 ns
runtime_iter: 23121 ns
runtime_part1: 40 ns
runtime_part2: 40 ns
runtime_part3: 30 ns
runtime_iter: 2440 ns
runtime_part1: 30 ns
runtime_part2: 40 ns
runtime_part3: 30 ns
runtime_iter: 2390 ns
print: 30 ns
runtime_measurement: 960 ns
```

Comment: Your benchmark probably isn't measuring what you think it is. Optimization can move things around, perform calculations at compile time, etc.

Comment: What takes more time of your code, by far, are the `println!` lines, that are included in `runtime_iter` but not in the `runtime_part*`.

Comment: @rodrigo - this is why there's a `runtime_measurement` at the bottom measuring that and disproving that claim, which was also my initial suspicion as I stated

Comment: Ah, your question is why that `runtime_iter: 23121` is so much higher than the next `runtime_iter: 2440`. That is probably a _hello world_ effect that punishes the very first call to `println!` (because that code is cache-cold) and maybe also `now()`. Try adding `println!("hello!");  let _ Instant::now();` just at the beginning of `main()` and see if it improves.

Comment: @rodrigo there is a sizeable change but the first iteration is still around 2 times higher (unless the Playground is under heavier load I guess  - when then results are more chaotic). I didn't know that it does that, really interesting and it makes sense:)

Comment: This is confirmed if you add a `println` at the beginning of `main` and time that: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aad5d51ec6b6f5d87473123a3449394e)

Comment: Taking the Jmb example and running it in Release mode makes this 2x effect practically disappear. Probably the multiplication, and the checked panics because of overflow were also cache-cold. There is still a small difference, maybe because of the 'Vec' code. This one reason why you usually measure a few thousands (or millions) iterations of your algorithm and then divide the time by that number: too much noise in a single short run.